# Align multi-line equations with implies

Tags: equations, align

I'd like to obtain something like,

```
   A + B = C + D
=> A + B + E = C + D + E
=> A + E = C + D + E - B
         = C + F - B
         = G - B
=> A + E + B = G
```

I've tried fiddling with align and alignat, but couldn't get what I want. The only way that I could think of is to use explicit value for horizontal space, which is very messy. Another solution is to use phantom, but again that seems cumbersome.

Any help regarding this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alignat(*)` works with the proper number of columns, and a `\quad` to give it some air:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
                    & & A + B & = C + D\\
   \Rightarrow\quad & & A + B & + E = C + D + E\\
   \Rightarrow\quad & & A + E & = C + D + E - B\\
                    & &       & = C + F - B\\
                    & &       & = G - B\\
   \Rightarrow\quad & & A + E & + B = G
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Here I've tried to reproduce your example as closely as possible. Personally, I'd align on the "=" sign, if you want that, just move the "&" to before the "=".

Comment: I can see that it works! But why do I need two "&" at the start of every line?

Comment: I think it has to do with the alignment: even columns (normally starting with the "=") are left-aligned, odd columns are right-aligned. So every "equation" in a line has to cover 2 columns to get the proper alignment

Comment: @ChesterX add some text into that blank column, you will see that it left aligns to the arrows, and is not needed here. (unlike a tabular ams alignments have no padding space so an empty column does not cause spurious space in the output)

Answer (score 1):

I would write it a bit differently, I see it less confusing if aligned at the `=` signs as below. An `array` can also be used efficiently here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l @{\quad} l @{{}={}} l}
               & A + B     & C + D\\
   \Rightarrow & A + B + E & C + D + E\\
   \Rightarrow & A + E     & C + D + E - B\\
               &           & C + F - B\\
               &           & G - B\\
   \Rightarrow & A + E + B & G
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]